# Передача параметра в статик метод

Tags: php, symfony2

Добрый день, я привык в Symfony2 делать следующим образом
В service.yml

```
 api.service.filter:
    class: ApiBundle\Service\FilterRule
    arguments:
        - "%some.parametr%"
```

В сервисе

```
 * @param $some
 */
public function __construct($some)
{
    $this->some = $some;
}
```

и потом в любом методе сервиса этот параметр получать через

```
$this->some
```

А тут столкнулся с тем что у меня есть вот такой код

```
 public static function fromParamFetcher(ParamFetcherInterface $fetcher)
{

    $input = new static();
    $input->code = $fetcher->get('code', $strict = true);
    $input->dateFrom = $fetcher->get('dateFrom', $strict = true);
    $input->dateTo = $fetcher->get('dateTo', $strict = true);
}
```

И сюда this->some уже не могу передать. Как тут правильно это сделать?

Comment: Можно конечно в контроллере передать этот параметр, когда дергаю сервис, но по моему это не очень хорошо будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так это же фабрика
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html

```
services:
    api.service.filter:
        class:   ApiBundle\Service\FilterRule
        factory: ["ApiBundle\Service\FilterRule", fromParamFetcher]
        arguments:
            - '@fetcher'
```

Но только в конце метода нужно добавить `return $input;`.

Answer (score 0):

Статический метод общий для всех экземпляров классов и может быть вызван без создания объектов.

```
ClassName::fromParamFetcher($fetcher);
```

Поэтому мы не можете задействовать внутри него ссылку `$this` на текущий объект - его просто нет. Вам нужно либо создать объект внутри такого статического класса, либо передать ему нужное значение через дополнительный параметр, либо объявить в классе статическую переменную с заранее заданным значением.